# Running scripts automatically

Tags: c#, webdriver

Does anyone know how to run Webdriver scripts from command line? I have written my tests in visualstudio2012 in c#. Now I have to make the run everyday basis automatically,
Please guide me.I want to run from command prompt

Answer (score 0):

1. Open up the Manage NuGet Packages window again (right-click on References under the project -> Manage NuGet Packages) and in the search box type "Selenium"
2. Select "Selenium Webdriver" and click Install to add Selenium references to your project.
3. Select "Selenium Webdriver Support Classes" and click Install -- these are some additional   references necessary to run Selenium tests in your Visual Studio solution.
4. Download IE Webdriver from the Selenium download page (choose the appropriate 32 or 64 bit version) and unzip.
5. Righ-click on the project name and click "Add existing item..."
6. Browse to the folder containing IEDriverServer.exe and choose that file to add to the project
7. Under the project tree right-click on the file and click Properties
8. Set the value of the field "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer"

For details check this -

http://dotnet.kapenilattex.com/?p=1097